# Eclipse "Navigate to the next item" shortcut on a file with deprecated items

Tags: java, eclipse

I use the "Navigate to the next/previous item" shortcut of Eclipse a lot when I am referencing a property on a Java File, and want to go to the next part of the code where I use it.

The shortcut, on Windows, is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> for *next* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> for *previous* use of that property (or variable, method, etc.)

When I am working on a file with deprecated items, the shortcut moves to the next/previous deprecated call (or reference), which really messes up with the initial purpose of the shortcut.

How can I avoid this to happen, and go to the next reference, even on a file with deprecated items?

Comment: Sounds like a great time saver but not working on mine at all. I'm wondering why is that now! I'm using Luna. You?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: You can switch on and off which elements that are included in the next/previous navigation. I included some information about this in my answer.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: I'm using Juno, and also happened, as Lii's answer explains why. Another shortcut I use is Ctrl + (shift) + K, as an alias to doing a search with Ctrl + F on the selected text, without opening the dialog. The pro of the next/previous against the Ctrl + K shortcut is it doesn't go by overloads or members with identical prefixes. On the other hand, Ctrl + K works well in most editors I've used.

Comment: Yes, I'm big on using keyboard shortcuts too. I had been using Ctrl + K all this time but the problem was that it worked like a substring search. So, it would go into log strings, variable or method names that match partially and what not. I'm so glad you posted this question (+1) as this "next/previous occurrence" thing was exactly what I needed! For errors/warnings, I was simply clicking on the red/yellow markers that show up right besides the scroll bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next/previous navigation feature you describe navigates between Eclipse's text *annotations*. (Not to be confused with the Java language construct.)

From your description it sound to me like this feature makes you jump to a deprecation warning, and a compile warning is a text annotation.

There is two ways to fix this that I can think of:

1. There is a setting for which annotation types that are included in the next/previous navigation in *Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations*. Here you can exclude Java warnings from next/previous navigation.
2. You could switch off warnings for the use of deprecated things in the compiler settings. They are located in *Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Deprecated and Restricted API*, either in the properties for a specific project or in the *Preference* dialog for all projects in the workspace.

**Extra tip**: The *Annotations* preference is very handy for a lot of different things, e.g. to change the appearance of break points or search results, to include or exclude them from next/previous navigation, etc.

Comment: This worked. I was able to turn navigation on for occurrences. +1

Comment: I used the first way and it worked well, as I don't see any use of the warnings in the next/previous navigation.

Comment: @jotaEsse: "_don't see any use of the warnings in the next/previous navigation_" It's very useful if you want to remove the source of the warnings! It's a good practice to remove the source of the warning, or to get rid of them with a `@SuppressWarnings`. But if there are many warnings in an old projects of course this might not be an option.